# Prove $\mathbb{S}^2$ is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I want to prove $\mathbb{S}^2$ is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$

I know $\mathbb{T}^2$ and $\mathbb{S}^2$ are not diffeomorphic, further they are not homeomorphic, but does not have any clue for proving this.

From the simple guess of gluing and tearing on torus or sphere i suspect they are not homeomorphic thus diffeomorphic. But i can not write down formal mathematical statement.

Comment: What is your background? Can you use de Rham cohomology, or differential forms, or the fundamental group?

Comment: @JackDavies, I just know some terminology on de Rham Cohomology, (not fully understand them) but well understanding about differential forms.Or fundamental groups. Here i want to know some formal proof via the definition of homeomorphism or diffeomorphism, not from topological invariants, like homotopy

Comment: @phy_math I doubt there is such thing. Algebraic topology exists for this very reason.

Comment: @phy_math: How do you define $T^2$? I ask because $T^n$ is defined, in general, as $(S^1)^n$. If you clarify your definition of $T^2$, then one approach would be to show that $S^1 \times S^1$ is diffeomorphic to $T^2$, and you know that the latter is not diffeomorphic to $S^2$.

Comment: @AlexM I know they are not diffeomorphic as a fact. What i want to know is how to prove they are not diffeomorphic in terms of diffeomorphism. Simply i can guess they are not homeomorphic from gluing or tearing or via topological invariants. (Many textbook states this reason) But what i want to know is how to show this from homeomorphism or diffeomorphism directly.  $i.e$, there is no such bijective map.

Comment: @phy_math: The only thing that I am saying is that in order to attempt a proof, I must know your definition of $T^2$. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

$\chi(S^2)=2$ and $\chi(S^1 \times S^1)=0$, but Euler characteristic is a topological invariant, so homeomorphic (and diffeomorphic) spaces should have equal $\chi$.